# Rails Time inconsistencies with rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, time, rspec

I'm working with Time in Rails and using the following code to set up the start date and end date of a project:

```
start_date ||= Time.now
end_date = start_date + goal_months.months
```

I then clone the object and I'm writing rspec tests to confirm that the attributes match in the copy.  <strike>The end dates match:</strike>

```
original[end_date]:  2011-08-24 18:24:53 UTC
clone[end_date]:     2011-08-24 18:24:53 UTC
```

but the spec gives me an error on the start dates:

```
expected: Wed Aug 24 18:24:53 UTC 2011,
     got: Wed, 24 Aug 2011 18:24:53 UTC +00:00 (using ==)
```

It's clear the dates are the same, just formatted differently.  How is it that they end up getting stored differently in the database, and how do I get them to match?  I've tried it with DateTime as well with the same results.

**Correction:**  The end dates don't match either.  They print out the same, but rspec errors out on them as well.  When I print out the start date and end date, the values come out in different formats:

```
start date: 2010-08-24T19:00:24+00:00
end date: 2011-08-24 19:00:24 UTC
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You should mock the now method of Time to make sure it always match the date in the spec. You never know when a delay will make the spec fail because of some milliseconds. This approach will also make sure that the time on the real code and on the spec are the same.

If you're using the default rspec mock lib, try to do something like:

```
t = Time.parse("01/01/2010 10:00")
Time.should_receive(:now).and_return(t)
```

Answer (score 52):

This usually happens because rspec tries to match different objects: Time and DateTime, for instance. Also, comparable times can differ a bit, for a few milliseconds.

In the second case, the correct way is to use stubbing and mock. Also see [TimeCop gem](http://rdoc.info/github/jtrupiano/timecop/master/file/README.rdoc)

In the first case, possible solution can be to compare timestamps:

```
actual_time.to_i.should == expected_time.to_i
```

I use simple [matcher](https://gist.github.com/1014456) for such cases:

```
# ./spec/spec_helper.rb
#
# Dir[File.dirname(__FILE__) + "/support/**/*.rb"].each {|f| require f}
#
#
# Usage:
#
# its(:updated_at) { should be_the_same_time_as updated_at }
#
#
# Will pass or fail with message like:
#
# Failure/Error: its(:updated_at) { should be_the_same_time_as 2.days.ago }
# expected Tue, 07 Jun 2011 16:14:09 +0300 to be the same time as Mon, 06 Jun 2011 13:14:09 UTC +00:00


RSpec::Matchers.define :be_the_same_time_as do |expected|
  match do |actual|
    expected.to_i == actual.to_i
  end
end
```

Comment: I'm getting this issue EVEN when using `Timecop`, which is really weird. Ideas?

Comment: Turns out this was only failing in our continuous integration environment. It seems as though it's a UTC vs non-UTC issue, so I'm just going to change my spec to `order.updated_at.utc.should == Time.now.utc`, which should fix it.

Comment: My fix didn't seem to work. Our CI environment still says:


    Diff:2012-11-19 23:54:24 UTC.==(2012-11-19 23:54:24 UTC) returned false even though the diff between 2012-11-19 23:54:24 UTC and 2012-11-19 23:54:24 UTC is empty. Check the implementation of 2012-11-19 23:54:24 UTC.==.

Comment: It looks like I'll be using `to_i` like everyone suggested. :) http://blog.tddium.com/2011/08/07/rails-time-comparisons-devil-details-etc/

Comment: Along with this matcher, we ended up using #beginning_of_xxx to 'round' the time prior to freezing with Timecop. E.g., `now = Time.now.beginning_of_hour` followed by `Timecop.freeze(now) do…end`

Comment: After reading the tddium blog article, I ended up just rounding my time before freezing it: https://github.com/travisjeffery/timecop/issues/122#issuecomment-39913650

Answer (score 23):

I totally agree with the previous answers about stubbing Time.now.  That said there is one other thing going on here.  When you compare datetimes from a database you lose some of the  factional time that can be in a ruby DateTime obj.  The best way to compare date in that way in Rspec is:

```
database_start_date.should be_within(1).of(start_date)
```

Answer (score 8):

One gotcha is that Ruby Time objects have nanosecond precision, but most databases have at most microsecond precision.  The best way to get around this is to stub Time.now (or use timecop) with a round number.  Read the post I wrote about this:  http://blog.solanolabs.com/rails-time-comparisons-devil-details-etc/

Comment: Ha, I just came here to add this link after stumbling upon it myself. I ended up wrapping Timecop in a method to round my time. https://github.com/travisjeffery/timecop/issues/122#issuecomment-39913650

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your specs, you might be able to use Rails-native [travel helpers](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Testing/TimeHelpers.html#method-i-travel_to):

```rb
# in spec_helper.rb
config.include ActiveSupport::Testing::TimeHelpers

start_date ||= Time.current.change(usecs: 0)
end_date = start_date + goal_months.months
travel_to start_date do
  # Clone here  
end
expect(clone.start_date).to eq(start_date)
```

Without `Time.current.change(usecs: 0)` it's likely to complain about the difference between time zones. Or between the microseconds, since the helper will reset the passed value internally (Timecop has a similar issue, so reset `usecs` with it too).

Answer (score 0):

My initial guess would be that the value of Time.now is formatted differently from your database value.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that you are using `==` and not `eql` or `be`? The latter two methods use object identity rather than comparing values.

From the output it looks like the expected value is a `Time`, while the value being tested is a `DateTime`. This could also be an issue, though I'd hesitate to guess how to fix it given the almost pathological nature of Ruby's date and time libraries ...

Comment: Do you get the same output when using DateTime instead of Time?

Answer (score 0):

One solution I like is to just add the following to `spec_helper`:

```
class Time
  def ==(time)
    self.to_i == time.to_i
  end
end
```

That way it's entirely transparent even in nested objects.

Comment: This seems like a bad idea to change the behavior of a core class in just your tests.

Comment: I actually ran into some issues with this as well, since there are a variety of Time-like classes that come up in Rails. I'll probably start integrating Timecop into my projects, though I suspect they do something similar.

Answer (score 0):

Adding `.to_datetime` to both variables will coerce the datetime values to be equivalent and respect timezones and Daylight Saving Time. For just date comparisons, use `.to_date`.

An example spec with two variables:
`actual_time.to_datetime.should == expected_time.to_datetime`

A better spec with clarity:
`actual_time.to_datetime.should eq 1.month.from_now.to_datetime`

`.to_i` produces ambiguity regarding it's meaning in the specs.

+1 for using TimeCop gem in specs. Just make sure to test Daylight Saving Time in your specs if your app is affected by DST.

Answer (score 0):

Our current solution is to have a `freeze_time` method that handles the rounding:

```
def freeze_time(time = Time.zone.now)
  # round time to get rid of nanosecond discrepancies between ruby time and
  # postgres time
  time = time.round
  Timecop.freeze(time) { yield(time) }
end
```

And then you can use it like:

```
freeze_time do
  perform_work
  expect(message.reload.sent_date).to eq(Time.now)
end
```